# ServiceStack.OrmLite CreateTable method ignores StringLength and DecimalLength attributes

Tags: attributes, servicestack, create-table, ormlite-servicestack

I tried it with PostgreSql provider. Digging into code I see that:

1. **OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.ToCreateTableStatement()** method strangely always passes null as **scale** parameter to **GetColumnDefinition()**.
2. **PostgreSQLDialectProvider.GetColumnDefinition()** ignores all parameters except **fieldType**

Is this intended to be so? Is there a workaround to make CreateTable consider fields length?

P.S. Is there an active issue tracker for ServiceStack? Link at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/How-to-contribute is broken.